# Is it possible to do a cooperative double match 2 players vs 2 cpu?

Tags: mario-tennis-ultra-smash

If I select double match mode with a second controller connected, I can't figure out how to play a cooperative double match with a friend against two CPU players.

Once I press <kbd>A</kbd> the game puts the second player automatically in the other team.

How can I change this? Is it even possible?

Comment: I think it is possible... I vaguely remember doing a 2 players vs 2 CPU... Might be wrong. Will try to check it at home tonight (If I remember doing it :$ )

Comment: @Karlyr ok I've found a solution, but I let you add an answer if you want :)

Comment: I'll add my photo of my screen (urghh) since I didn't find any and I doesn't have a capture card / fancy TV. But you didn't have to wait ;)

Comment: @Karlyr LOL that photo is clear enough, don't worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the next to last screen, where you chose sets and games, you can chose the positions of each characters. You have 3 settings allowing any characters to play with any others.

[image]

Comment: Pretty counterintuitive, but thank you!